# The usage of phrase "come to mind"

Tags: phrase-usage

Someone asked "*If the term ‘Kurds’ was changed to ‘Curds’, then would Iran, Turkey, and Iraq allow a new country called ‘Curdistan’?*" which seems like a silly question.

I jokingly wrote:

> Wow!
>
> Why didn’t it come to anyone's mind before?! very subtle point!

Is it a correct usage of "come to mind"?

Comment: I don't get the joke.

Comment: "Why didn't anyone think of that before?" is common.

Comment: @mr it was just a silly question. And I answered it pretending that is an excellent idea.

Comment: Agree with "Why didn't anyone think of that before?" as the standard phrasing, though I would be really cautious about using it. It can be read as sarcastic and come across as rude or dismissive.

Answer (score 0):

Be recollected, occur to one, as in *A new idea just came to mind.* This phrase replaced the earlier *come in mind*, which dates from the late 1300s. Also see BRING TO MIND; CALL TO MIND; ENTER ONE’S MIND.

American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms 2nd Ed.

Answer (score 0):

"Come to mind" is a set idiom, and inserting an agent into it is usually un-idiomatic. The phrase is almost always used in the first person, about things that occurred to the speaker.

Unless you're quoting something that someone else said or narrating in an omniscient point of view, you should avoid using the phrase "come to mind" about anyone other than yourself.